# How to run Cucumber Junit runner class in BDD Framework using NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, bdd, junit5, netbeans-plugins, junit-runner

I am trying to run my simple login scenario in NetBeans (UI Test) using selenium and Java.

Used BDD Framework and trying to run Junit (Runner) class, but not able to see even run as Junit option in NetBeans.

Excellent if you can help with this.

Regards,
Rajesh Bathula

Comment: To give others a chance to help you, you have to provide a lot more information, e.g.: version of NetBeans, Maven or Gradle configuration, at least one test class, cucumber file and directory structure. This is the minimum.

Comment: NetBeans Version: 8.1

Comment: Used below technologies:

Selenium, Java, Maven
Hope we(selenium professionals) very well about cucumber runner file) I'm just trying to run that file, but in Netbeans, it's always finding for the main method to execute the scripts.

Let me know if you need any more information, Thank you for your suggestion.